# How to I get ruby `print` to echo to calling bash script?

Tags: ruby, bash, shell

I'm calling ruby from a bash shell script, like

```
#!/bin/bash

# lots of stuff

ruby script.rb

# more stuff
```

I'd like the things I `print` in the ruby script to show up in stdout for the shell script, but they don't. Strangely, whatever I use `p` on *does* show up. How can I get this to work for `print`?

---

**Quick answer:** use `puts`.

Comment: `print` output goes to stdout. There is no special Ruby magic involved. Of course it doesn't mean that you immediately see the output (due to buffering), but at least if the Ruby program terminates, you should see the output. There are two things to check: Do you use the correct `print`? Maybe the method has been redefined. Use `$stdout.print` instead. Second, pipe the Ruby output to `xxd`. Maybe there are some control characters which erase the line being printed so quickly, that you can't see it. Note also that `print` does not output a `\n` automatically.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My guess is this has to do with STDOUT buffering. `p` flushes the buffer immediately, while `print` does not. Use `puts` instead, which also flushes, or you can set STDOUT to always flush globally with:

```
$stdout.sync = true
```

To flush on a case-by-case basis, you can always call `flush` yourself:

```
print ...
print ...
print ...
$stdout.flush
```